# How can I test Log4j2's HTTP Appender in my Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, http, log4j2

I've set up Log4j2 into my Spring Boot application and while I am able to test FileAppender by simply checking the contents of the file and seeing if my logs are being written, I have no idea on how I should test that my HTTP Appender is configured correctly.

```
    <Http name="Http" url="myEndPoint">
      <Property name="X-Java-Runtime" value="$${java:runtime}" />
      <JsonLayout properties="true"/>
    </Http>
  </Appenders>
```

HTTP Appender takes a URL and sends a POST request to that url but how can I test to see that it's working? I plan using `httpbin.org/anything` as my url. `/anything` returns whatever you send it, so if my HTTP Appender works, I should receive my logs back in the response of the request but how do I print the **content of the response**? There is no field in log4j2 that allows it to print the response.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to write an automated test?

Comment: Why not just run a servlet locally which writes to a file, and check the file contents?

Comment: Why not check with its intended target rather than another target?